# Is it possible to run a difference-in-differences analysis when the "treatment" in applied gradually?

Tags: difference-in-difference

The treatment consists in joining an association which imposes certain rules. Joining is however voluntary and for this reasons happens gradually over the last 10 years. I have data before and after joining for each member and data for a control group. There might also be a period of "inertia" after joining, period in which the members need to adjust to the new policy so the results might not be noticeable right away. Is DD applicable in this framework?

Comment: Isn't it somehow similar to (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36024/difference-in-differences-id-switches-between-treatment-and-control-group )[this]? Your members who have not joined yet are part of the control group, until they join the association and become treated. This is my thought but I am also hesitant.